# "End Of TNS Channel" when running multiple SQOOP jobs (1.4)

Tags: java, oracle, sqoop

I have a requirement which requires me to trigger mutiple parallel SQOOP jobs from separate JVM sessions. 
Thus I cannot use OOZIE to trigger the jobs in parallel. When I trigger the jobs separately I am getting the below error :

```
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: End of TNS data channel
java.sql.SQLException: End of TNS data channel
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.makeConnection(OracleManager.java:327)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:736)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:759)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:269)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
```

If I trigger them sequentially they execute without any issues. 
The below are some salient points about my job :

- They need to execute in parallel
- The **do not** connect to the same table
- They connect to the same database (Oracle)
- I am using SQOOP 1.4 bundled with cloudera 5.3.2

I tried to find if there was any reported issue with SQOOP parallel run but couldn't find any.

Thanks.

Comment: Am having the same usecase, any success?

Comment: What we found is that this is more of a problem with the VM. When we tried to open multiple JDBC connections within a VM we faced this issue. Once we moved to actual physical machines we did not face this issue. Hope this helps.